# How to detect if device support notch display?

Tags: android

Currently I am facing a problem to detect if mobile device support notch display in android.

Can any one help me in this? (I need to do this using code in android studio)

Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Still searching a solution no idea how to do this

Comment: I don't remember any API that provides this information at all, I can only think of getting the device name or (any identity) that will identify the device and create a fix list of device that has notch and lastly compare the device name to your list, this might not cover all devices but it is a lot better that nothing at all.

Comment: Currently it is not possible it seems. Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50482390/how-can-we-get-the-size-of-screen-with-notch-on-the-top/50482572

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Some Oreo devices also have notch display if you are targeting to support all OS then you can use my solution. As per material design guidelines the status bar height for Android devices is 24dp. You can get device status bar height and device density by using the following and check if status bar height is more than 24dp. If its height is more than 24dp then it has the notch on display and then you can handle your view position as per your requirement. This will work on Oreo as well.

```
int statusBarHeight = 0;
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if (resourceId > 0) {
    statusBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
}
```

// DP to Pixels

```
public static int convertDpToPixel ( float dp){
    DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return Math.round(px);
}
```

// Make UI adjustments as per your requirement

```
if (statusBarHeight > convertDpToPixel(24)) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams topbarLp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    topbarlp.setMargins(0, statusBarHeight, 0, 0);

    //Set above layout params to your layout which was getting cut because of notch
    topbar.setLayoutParams(topbarlp)
}
```

Comment: This is not working for infinity-O displays (samsung s10)

Comment: This solution is for detecting and handing notch display

Comment: Yes but these samsung s10 devices statusBarHeight is 24. We may need some generic solution.

Comment: @Pandiri Please check my answer. 
I am checking if status bar height is "Greater than 24dp". 
Because as per material design status bar height is 24 dp. 
If their is a notch then it gets increased. 
And samsung s10 has infinity display so it is different thing and it doesn't have notch so its height is 24dp. 
Infinity display need to handle in different way.

Comment: Use 25 instead of 24.

Comment: @AhamadullahSaikat do you found any device with 25dp status bar height and without knotch?

Comment: if in landscape mode, the "status_bar_height" seems to be 84, and even though the notch is not UI blocking the status_bar, the notch UI blocks the left or right sides of the app so need to also check for this scenario and make adjustments

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the [getDisplayCutout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsets#getDisplayCutout()) method of the [WindowInsets](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsets) object. This will give you a [DisplayCutout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/DisplayCutout) object, which you can query to find the "safe" insets within the display.

The DisplayCutout class is new in API level 28, so you won't be able to do it on devices with a lower API level (you can assume that there's no notch unless it's API level >= 28).

There's a guide [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout/).

You can get hold of the WindowInsets object by overriding the [onApplyWindowInsets](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onApplyWindowInsets(android.view.WindowInsets)) method of the View, or by implementing a [OnApplyWindowInsetsListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) class.

Comment: thanks for reponse but in market there are many devices which support notch even with less then api version 28

Comment: Try to use DisplayCutoutCompat in the AndroidX library - it suppose to work on older api versions .