# Check if device has notch in service

Tags: android, android-hardware, windowinsets

I've an app with an overlay and I need to check if the device has a notch or not.

Normally you use the activity and call following:

```
activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootWindowInsets().getDisplayCutout()
```

Any alternative way to check for a notch that also works in a service? I need to adjust my overlay if the device has a notch...

Any way to find out if the device has a notch or not if I can only access the `WindowManager`?

Comment: Check my answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53593067/10477142

Comment: Thanks, this may help, but is no bullet proof solution. E.g. you can modify statusbar height on rooted devices to whatever you want - many custom ROMs offer small patches for this... And I would not rely on the assumption you make, although the assumption that all devices without notches have a statusbar height of 24dp may be true for all devices (not sure though, manufactures don't always follow googles design suggestions).