# How to get correct screen dimensions for Android Phone with notch

Tags: java, android, screen, dimensions

I'm making a game for Android using Java, I need to map the game screen dimensions to the device screen dimensions, I used to use the following code to get the device screen dimensions

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int width=dm.widthPixels;
int height=dm.heightPixels;
```

I face a problem with new devices with a notch, the above code gives me different screen height than the actual device, for example, the actual device height is 2340 pixels but the code returned 2130 pixels, I used the following code to get the notch height

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    DisplayCutout displayCutout = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootWindowInsets().getDisplayCutout();
    if (displayCutout.getBoundingRects().size() > 0) {
        Rect notchRect = displayCutout.getBoundingRects().get(0);
    }
}
```

which is 80, now 2130 + 80 is 2210, there are still 130 pixels missing when I map the game screen to the device screen, a shift happens due to the incorrect height

Comment: are you testing it on a device with Android P?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53593067/6514945

Comment: @sanjeev yes I'm testing on a device with Android P, please note that I know how to detect if the device has a notch, and I know how to get the notch dimensions, my problem is how to get the screen height in pixels, because the ordinary method returns wrong height

Comment: Check the answer properly. He checks for status bar height if it's more than 24dp while you are using the Android method to determine it.

Comment: And then? I need to get the total screen height in pixels

Answer (score 0):

Until now there is no way to get the real dimensions of the screen with a notch

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getRealMetrics instead of getMetrics?