# hide/show status bar with notches

Tags: java, android, statusbar

I am building an app that needs to hide/show status bar. It works well for phones without notches, but I can't find a way to hide/show the status bar in phones with notches. Is there a way to handle different notches for the status bar?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use activity flag to show and hide status bar. You can use following code in manifest for hide status bar for specific activity.

```html
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

You can also change flag at run time.

```html
// Hide status bar
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
// Show status bar
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

You can also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53593067/9792247) whether device has notch display or not and according to this you can manage that flag to show and hide status bar.