# How to find out if an android device has a notch and softkey?

Tags: android, navigation, operating-system

I am trying to find out if an **android** device has **softkeys** and **notch**. I am able to find out **softkey** presence by this logic:

```
    private fun hasSoftKeys(windowManager: WindowManager): Boolean {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            val d = windowManager.defaultDisplay
            val realDisplayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
            d.getRealMetrics(realDisplayMetrics)
            val realHeight = realDisplayMetrics.heightPixels
            val realWidth = realDisplayMetrics.widthPixels
            val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
            d.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
            val displayHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels
            val displayWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels
            return realWidth - displayWidth > 0 || realHeight - displayHeight > 0
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

But it's failing for devices with **notch**. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52514411/7557205

Comment: Using that i can only find out if a device has notch or not . it doesn't give any idea about softkey.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983621/detect-soft-navigation-bar-availability-in-android-device-progmatically